# The problem about DEEP-FIRST SEARCH of undirected graph

Tags: c

I want to build an undirected graph saved by adjacency list and use dfs algorithm to test the graph, but I can't get the answer I expected. What is the problem of my program? Is my dfs() function or my insert() function wrong ? Thank you for answer!

The whole thing is that I build  two array respectively, The one, visited[MAX_VERTEX], is used to save the node I has printed. if visited[i] is TRUE, it show that node i has already printed. The other is a array, adjlist[MAX_VERTEX] , save many pointer to the structure,"struct node".adjlist[i] is a headnode of linked list.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_VERTEX 8
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *link;
};

short int visited[MAX_VERTEX];//global array for already visited vertex
struct node *adjlist[MAX_VERTEX];//array save pointer to node

void insert(int v, struct node *vertex);
void dfs(int v);

int main(void){//graph saved with adjacency list
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_VERTEX; i++){ //initialize both adjlist and visited array
        adjlist[i] = NULL;
        visited[i] = FALSE;
    }
    struct node init_node = {0,NULL};
    insert(1,&init_node);
    insert(2,&init_node);
    init_node.data = 3;
    insert(1,&init_node);
    insert(7,&init_node);
    init_node.data = 7;
    insert(4,&init_node);
    insert(5,&init_node);
    insert(6,&init_node);
    init_node.data = 4;
    insert(1,&init_node);
    init_node.data = 2;
    insert(5,&init_node);
    insert(6,&init_node);
    
    dfs(0);
    
    return 0;
}

void dfs(int v){ //deep first search
    struct node *cur;
    visited[v] = TRUE;
    printf("%5d ", v);
    cur = adjlist[v];
    while(cur != NULL){
        if(visited[cur->data] == FALSE)
            dfs(cur->data);
        cur = cur->link;
    }
    return; 
}

void insert(int v, struct node *vertex){ //form the edge(v,vertex->data) 
    struct node *ptr, *temp;
    temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp));
    
    ptr = adjlist[v];
    if(ptr == NULL)
        ptr = vertex;
    else{
        for(; (ptr != NULL)&& ((ptr->link) != NULL); ptr = ptr->link){ //ptr point to the last node of adjlist[v]
            if(ptr->data == v){
                fprintf(stderr,"The node\"%d\" has already existed ");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }   
        ptr->link = vertex;
    }
    
    ptr = adjlist[vertex->data];
    temp->data = v;
    temp->link = NULL;
    if(ptr == NULL)
        ptr = temp;
    else{
        for(; (ptr != NULL)&& ((ptr->link) != NULL); ptr = ptr->link){ //ptr point to the last node of adjlist[vertex->data]
            if(ptr->data == vertex->data){
                fprintf(stderr,"The node\"%d\" has already existed ");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
        ptr->link = temp;
    }
    return;
}

/***********************************************************************
Thanks for answer.Following is the code I revise for "insert" function.
***********************************************************************/

void new_node(int v,int value){
    struct node *ptr, *temp;
    temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp));
    temp->data = value;
    temp->link = NULL;
    
    if(adjlist[v] == NULL) 
        adjlist[v] = temp; 
    else{
        ptr = adjlist[v];
        for(; (ptr != NULL)&& ((ptr->link) != NULL); ptr = ptr->link){ //ptr point to the last node of adjlist[v]
            if((ptr->data == v) || (ptr->data == value)){
                fprintf(stderr,"The node has already existed ");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }   
        ptr->link = temp;
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through with debugger?  What did you find?  You have identified two potential areas of interest, why do you think they are potential problems?  _"What is wrong with my program"_ is too general a question.   If you ask specific questions you will arrive more quickly to specific answers.

Comment: I'm a beginner  in C language, I wrote the program with nopad++. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It feels like you're making things way more complicated than they need to be. If you're going to limit yourself to a set amount of nodes, you should really just use the array indexes to access the data instead of dealing with pointer magic. If you really want a dynamic structure, then you really should only depend on the structs pointers and avoid dealing with arrays because they'll make your life harder.

Additionally, instead of your insert function, I would do something like:

```
n0 = new_node(0, NULL); // new_node(data, linked node)
n1 = new_node(1, &n0);
...
```

It would be so much easier to read. And you probably wouldn't need to keep that global array around.

That said, I think the main problem here is that `adjlist[i]` is never set to anything but `NULL`. I've added a couple of prints here so you can visualize: https://onlinegdb.com/CqZt3I4DL

More specifically, this line in the insert function:

```
ptr = adjlist[v];
if (ptr == NULL)
    ptr = vertex; // <-- massive mistake
```

Is a massive mistake, because it assumes `ptr` and `adjlist[v]` will share the same value. While this is true for the value they point to, that is not true for the pointer itself. After that line, `ptr` points to `&vertex` while `adjlist[v]` is still `NULL`. These lines should really read:

```
ptr = adjlist[v];
if (ptr == NULL)
    adjlist[v] = vertex; // ptr is overwritten some lines bellow.
```